# What do these things have in common? (Albert Iteration)

Tags: riddle, word, pattern, cryptic-clues

Following is a list of lines; each line contains two riddles written by my pal Albert Iteration. Each riddle describes a single word. Your task is to identify the words being described and find what the two words in each line have in common (if there are multiple answers, choose the largest). They're in no particular order, there are easy ones sprinkled in there but I think this one shouldn't last too long on here.
For clarity, I have added an asterisk to lines that still need solving. As progress is made, I will remove the asterisks

```
 system's subdivision       | deviation; death  
 lobotomee's loss           | employed entities  
 crystal clear              | overtly obvious  
 handsy humanoid            | atmospheric ambience  
*headdress holiday          | chromosomal cross-up  
 lacking logic              | evoking enthusiasm            
*incumbent inhabitant       | ascent apex  
*cache contribution         | simultaneous states  
*multi-tasking mycota       | mammals' mark  
 drink denier               | absolute autocracy  
 sunday solver              | sage's saying  
 successfully settle        | pardon, papally  
 not normal                 | kanye's kin  
 incorrectly interpreted    | college kid  
 material metamorphosis     | knowledge; news  
 celestial species          | bachelor brotherhood  
*wowing wizardry            | hearty herb  
 similar starts             | repeated recounting  
 formal familiarization     | orchestral outlier  
 supremely significant      | placebo peddler  
 immeasurably insignificant | certainly so  
*gun; gum                   | worthless whistle  
*meagerly mindful           | chitined crustacean  
*supervised span            | pulsate periodically  
 wrestle; wrangle           | fragmented fruit  
 prophetic portender        | ceremonial start  
 replicate ravenously       | water ward  
*palpable proximity         | person picked
```

And if you really want to impress, I think it would be fun if you could come up with your own two word riddles in Al's style for each answer. This is not necessary to get the green check, however. Alright have fun!!

EDIT:
And of course, when it comes to answers with multiple parts like this one, partial answers are always welcome.

Clarification for those who know the gimmick/pattern:

> All of the shared words will be relatively common English words (though one is a little more archaic) that can be found on dictionary.com. There are no proper nouns and no words shorter than 3 letters.

Comment: Would cryptic-clues be a good tag match for this puzzle?

Comment: Note that the two words to the left of the pipe are alliterative. The words on the right are often but not always so.

Comment: Hey, nobody's perfect @EngineerToast. Sometimes you have to use a little imagination lol

Comment: Well, alliteration doesn't have to be the same letter, just the same sound

Comment: Hmm I can't tell if people are stumped, or if they're trying to get it all in go (or for that matter, if no one is working on it at all). Anyone made any amount of progress?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised at the lack of feedback, too. I think I've solved maybe a third of the clues, probably the easier ones, but I've posted an answer to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 10):

I have only a partial solution to offer, but I'm sure I won't solve all riddles, so I'll share what I have so far.

The solutions below have two spoilers each. The first is my attempt at a two-word riddle that describes what the other two have in common, which may be awkwardly phrased and no help at all. The second explains my solution.

system's subdivision | deviation; death

> → component; constituent

►

> **part**ition, de**part**ure

crystal clear | overtly obvious

> → actual ancestor

►

> trans**parent**, ap**parent**

drink denier | absolute autocracy

> → added-up amount

►

> tee**total**ler, **total**itarianism

sunday solver | sage's saying

> → possible predicate

►

> cruci**verb**ialist, pro**verb**

successfully settle | pardon, papally

> → penetrate problem

►

> re**solve**, ab**solve**

material metamorphosis | knowledge; news

> → plane pattern

►

> trans**formation**, in**formation**

celestial species | bachelor brotherhood

> → (fall flower)

►

> (**aster**oid, mon**aster**y) (not correct, see comments)

similar starts | repeated recounting

> → procedural progression

►

> all**iteration**, re**iteration**

formal familiarization | orchestral outlier

> → tear transporter

►

> intro**duct**ion, con**duct**or

supremely significant | placebo peddler

> → sturdy steed

►

> para**mount**, **mount**ebank

immeasurably insignificant | certainly so

> → ever ending

►

> in**finite**simal, de**finite**ly

wrestle; wrangle | fragmented fruit

> → modern music

►

> g**rap**ple, g**rap**es (thanks to TroyAndAbed, see comments)

prophetic portender | ceremonial start

> → bygone birdwatcher

►

> **augur**, in**augur**ation

Comment: Some (possibly bad) guesses:
wrestle; wrangle | fragmented fruit  -> g**rap**ple | g**rap**e -> rap

Comment: palpable proximity | person picked  -> clo**sen**ess | cho**sen** -> sen (money in japan )

Comment: @TroyAndAbed Japanese money is "yen" (or "en"). "Sen" can mean "thousand" though.

Comment: Yes, just misread http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sen?s=t

Comment: Woo glad to know someone is in fact working on it. You've made awesome progress. All of the ones you have so far match what I have except celestial species | bachelor brotherhood. That is one of the slightly harder ones that feature a hint of wordplay

Comment: Oh and wonderful work on alliterative descriptions, I especially like tear transporter and penetrate problem

Comment: @TroyAndAbed: Thanks for your suggestions. I've added "rap", but I'm not so sure about "sen". I hope you're okay with that.

Comment: @MOehm No problem, that why I added that it was possibly bad!

Comment: @MOehm I have awarded the bounty to this answer. It's about to expire and you were 1. the first to crack the pattern and 2. the contributor of the most solutions, so I feel it's appropriate. If you think you can wrap up the last few, then you get all-revered green check as well

Comment: Oh, my first bounty, thanks. I haven't tackled any of them for a while. I might give it another go but I'm afriad that I won't get any further.

Answer (score 3):

It took looking at M Oehm's solution for it to click for me, but here's my contribution so far:

Lobotomee's loss | employed entities

> **person**ality | **person**el

lacking logic | evoking enthusiasm

> Ir**ration**al | Inspi**ration**al

Not normal | Kanye's kin

> U**north**odox | **North**

Incorrectly interpreted | College kid

> Mis**under**stood | **under**graduate

<strike>Wowing wizardry | Hearty herb</strike>

> Be**witch**ment | **Witch**hazel

Headdress holiday | chromosomal cross-up

> f**esti**val | transv**esti**te

Comment: Nice job on the first one. Your second solution is incorrect, though if it's any consolation, it made me laugh out loud in surprise. To be more helpful, it's off because a festival doesn't really have anything to do with headresses (except that sometimes people wear them)

Comment: Ah, I was thinking along the lines of Carnival - festival

Comment: Nice additions. All correct except the witch guess

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of my guesses:

handsy humanoid | atmospheric ambience

> pri**mate** / cli**mate**

headdress holiday | chromosomal cross-up

> **car**nival / **car**cinogenic

lacking logic | evoking enthusiasm

> ir**ration**al / vene**ration**

multi-tasking mycota | mammals' mark  (not sure about the "multitasking" part...)

> porta**bell**a / **bell**ybutton

celestial species | bachelor brotherhood

> ext**rate**rrestial / f**rate**rnity

wowing wizardry | hearty herb

> bran**dish** / horsera**dish**

gun; gum | worthless whistle

> t**ride**nt / de**ride** (probably wrong but oh well)

supervised span | pulsate periodically

> hos**pita**lization / pal**pita**te

replicate ravenously | water ward

> pro**life**rate / **life**saver

palpable proximity | person picked

> im**mine**nt / no**mine**e

Comment: Nice work. I've removed the asterisk from the OP for the ones that were correct. lacking logic was solved correctly by M Oehm already. You're close with mammal's mark, just think of another distinctly mamallian feature. AFAIK, all mammal's feature this, whereas platypi don't have belly buttons (though it seems unfair to cite the billed enigma that is the platypus)