# Are You All of These, or Just The One?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I am looking for someone to be my match.  Try this riddle to see if it's you.

> This riddle is slightly different, but I think you will get used to it with time.
>
> Your brain is evolved, is it not? Then you should have two legs to stand on.
>
> Feel free to sketch out your ideas or to draw quick conclusions.
>
> After all, we are all open to learning new ideas from our peers.
>
> I hope this doesn’t make you too heated, though.
>
> You might think that we are both stuck, forces equally matched.
>
> But perhaps you thought less of this riddle than you should have.
>
> Now that I have you where I want you, the end is inevitable.
>
> And here it is: it is final.
>
> Hopefully my hints aren’t too subtle, for I would love you to get the answer, or at least to get close.

Each line corresponds to one word and each word corresponds with the others.  Once you get one, the rest should be fairly easy.  Figure all the words out and you just may be my match.

And if you are my match, who are you?

Hint:

> If you are my match, you may not be all of these, but you just may be The One.

Hint 2:

> The words from each line do more than simply correspond with each other; there is a common element between all of them.

Hint 3:

> I've said that the words you should get from each line correspond to one another, but it may be more appropriate to say that there is a relationship between them.  It may be important to think in those terms.

Comment: Is this related to The Matrix Trilogy? "brain","inevitable" and "The One" makes me feel the riddle has got something to do with it.

Comment: @shettysahab I figured that comparison would be drawn, but this "The One" has very different connotations from the one in The Matrix.  This "One" is a concept in our reality, but whether it exists or not is subjective.

Comment: Is the last line of your first spoiler block part of the riddle? The one with "Hopefully my hints..."

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is part of the riddle, but it might not be as straightforward, since it is hinting at two definitions for the same word.  Obviously finding the common element between all the words would be avast help to all.

Comment: Does the answer have anything to do with science/scientists? General relativity, anti-matter, physics, etc? Or am I barking up the wrong tree with that?

Comment: @JoeMalpass Sorry to say that it's the wrong tree.  But for your trouble, I'll tell you that I haven't made any typos (including in the comment to Tom, wink wink, nudge nudge).

Comment: Well... I can see what you're alluding to there, but my brain is having a slow day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I'm pretty sure it's referring to...

> ...words with **"mate"** in them

*This riddle is slightly different, but I think you will get used to it with time.*

> Accli**mate**

*Your brain is evolved, is it not? Then you should have two legs to stand on.*

> Pri**mate**

*Feel free to sketch out your ideas or to draw quick conclusions.*

> Esti**mate** / Guessti**mate**

*After all, we are all open to learning new ideas from our peers.*

> School**mates** / Class**mate**s

*I hope this doesn’t make you too heated, though.*

> Inflam**mate**

*You might think that we are both stuck, forces equally matched.*

> Stale**mate**

*But perhaps you thought less of this riddle than you should have.*

> Underesti**mate**

*Now that I have you where I want you, the end is inevitable.*

> Check**mate**

*And here it is: it is final.*

> Ulti**mate**

*Hopefully my hints aren’t too subtle, for I would love you to get the answer, or at least to get close.*

> Approxi**mate**

*Be my match, or be The One*

> Find words with **"mate"** in them, or soul**mate** / the word **"mate"** itself / legti**mate**

*"Avast!"*

> "Ahoy **mate**y" =)

Comment: Note: the pirate clue together with [this previous riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/what-do-these-things-have-in-common-albert-iteration/20619#20619) helped me a lot

Comment: Very nicely done.  It surprised me how many alternate, yet equally acceptable answers there were for a few of these, but that just goes to show how creative everyone on here is.  The one is indeed a soulmate, or simply a mate, and yes, avast makes me think immediately of ahoy matey.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer:**

I noticed all of those could be

> Something like emotions/feelings/... In order: 
> Patience, Reason, Excitement, Motivation, Anger, Despair, Regret, Satisfaction, Relief, Hope

Now I'm having trouble to find *the one* though ;)

Comment: Not quite there, but I do like the way you are thinking, and there are certainly emotions that go along with these words.  What connects the words to each other most of all, however, is not so much their definitions, but instead their construction.  I have edited one of the lines that had bugged me a bit.  See if any of this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Partial guess:

I wanted to just ask a question in the comments but I don't have enough (any) reputation.

> Does it have anything to do with elements (periodic table or lore e.g. fire air water etc)? You mentioned "element" in a hint and in a comment, but that could just be you liking the word's description of the riddle. I'm leaning towards water.

Reasoning:

> "Getting used to something over time" Water dissolves other elements and normally makes them safer by doing so. Also diffusion, but that's a stretch (most of this is)
>
>  Water has two hydrogen "legs";
>
>  Got nothing for this one. Water adapts and is a liquid?
>
>  "Learning things from peers" is interacting/heating up when dissolving other elements/molecules
>
>  This one's a stretch, but water is a solute, and lots of dissolving reactions produce heat.
>
>  Stuck together implying a bond
>
>  Nobody expects water? This is looking weaker
>
>  I have nothing for the "end is inevitable" or "final" aswell

Additional things from hints:

> Elements match into different molecules; 
>
>  "the one" could by indicating hydrogen;
>
>  you could be oxygen with the match being water;

looking into this a bit more, the other thing I could think of was:

> a pirate. "two legs" mocking peg legs, "avast" is a nautical term/pirate slang. Avast also means halt, but... nothing with match or the one.

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines with your last guess there, though for the common element I went off thinking about gold instead of water, didn't get anywhere with that though. Now I'm thinking the common feature is five letter words that start with A (which has two legs), but that's a struggle too. I noticed that some of the OP's other riddles focus on a series of related video games...

Comment: @getfugu You're correct in picking up that avast is pirate slang, and I dropped it in there to hopefully spur the thoughts of other pirate slang.  Doing so might help you identify that common feature (sorry, nothing to do with elements...or video games).

Comment: @JoeMalpass You have identified that all the words share a similar construction, which is key.  Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question, as the current answers don't reflect this, but I can tell you that the words do vary in length and they all *start* with something different.

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with pirate slang. I assume you are hinting that they all have the same ending. Then for "The One" clue, the only thing I can think of other than the Matrix is Tolkien's One Ring to Rule Them All, but I don't have any way to relate it to anything else, especially pirates. Oh well...